# How to disable Google Cloud Messaging Service for a package name

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

From [Google Developers - Enable Google services for your app](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) I've enabled Google Cloud Messaging for a specific package name.

Then I figured out that the package name I enabled the service for was wrong, so I added the right one.

Now, how can I remove the wrong package name from list of enabled packages? Having both registered causes the downloaded google-services.json file to contain also the details of wrong package name.

In the Google Developers Console -> Cloud Messaging for Android there are no options listed, only enable / disable API. I disebled the API but repeating the procedure still leads to the same result, with JSON containing both package names.

Comment: In the credentials section. Google Developers Console -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials. Have you tried removing Client IDs or Keys with references to the package name you want to remove?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In credentials pane I can see no client IDs, I only have the public access key I created for the server that havo to push messages to client apps.

Comment: What type of client app are you using? The package name of the client app, receiving the notifications, should be set in the Google Developer Console.

Comment: I'm going to use an Android app and I began by creating a configuration file as per [this guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). During this procedure I made the mistake, when repeating the procedure everything was ok but now in config file I find listed both right and wrong package name.

Comment: I believe that the config file should represent the state of your Google Developer Console credentials. But even if it does not, you should be able to open the downloaded config file (JSON file) and manually remove references to the unwanted package name.

Comment: I agree with you but can't find this match. My problem is not to "clean" json config file, while avoiding having a possible "open door" for an app I don't own. It's not clear to me if the infos in that config files are only used by client to get its device/app token or are also known by Google's API project

Comment: I think you should create a new `Android key` to your specific package name instead of `Server key` for the all

Comment: Same problem here. Created a project, filled in package name A, enabled GCM and Analytics. Then changed the package name, followed the steps again. The downloaded google-services.json now contains both package names. Perhaps the question should be changed in, how can you remove a package name from a project in the google developer console? I added both packages using the form: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Comment: Same here. I cannot find the packages I created so far anywhere.

Comment: Is anyone here still experiencing this issue? Does disabling and re-enabling it allow you erase created packages, essentially starting over?

Comment: @Paolone if you were able to resolve this, you can post it as an answer so that any community member seeing this same issue can have the solution. If not, providing further information as Nicholas requested would help further this.

Comment: If you are still experiencing this issue, it is recommended to use the new replacement to [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) called [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Answer (score 0):

*As this is an old user-end question that is no longer active, I will be posting the last comment as the answer.*

If you are still experiencing issues with [Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/), it is recommended to use the new [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) as it is the [designed replacement](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm).